# .htaccess used as "database"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm gonna write a script that will provide to users a way to get a link to a resource stored in my server, and they will have the ability to delete the link in any moment to prevent people with that link to reach the resource.

So I have:

```
/imgs/res1.jpg
/imgs/res2.jpg
.htaccess
```

And in .htaccess I've

```
Redirect 301 /userdefinedalias /imgs/res1.jpg
Redirect 301 /userdefinedalias2 /imgs/res1.jpg
Redirect 301 /userdefinedalias3 /imgs/res2.jpg
```

I would like to use .htaccess and not PHP+MySQL because .htaccess is much faster.

I need a very very fast way to redirect to the right resource because these links will be used to provide UV textures to meshes in a videogame (like Second Life) and I can't make the game lag if in the same space there are 20/30 textures provided by my links.

My problem is that I will have probably thousand of different links, I don't know how Apache will responds to this situation and I don't know if there are better ways to do it.

Any advice?

Comment: This is silly, use a MySQL server as it is designed excel in these kind of tasks.

Comment: If you're using .htaccess and redirects to do this, you're adding overhead already... why not just use a database?

Comment: @Mark Baker: I need to give alias links because them must be removable in any moment without deleting the resource and without break other alias which point to the same resource.

Comment: @Joren: MySQL+PHP are too slow for this task.

Comment: Keep in mind that redirects might be cached...

Comment: So an enabled/disabled flag on a database isn't an option? And MYSQL is too slow? What kind of database indexing don't you have? A properly designed database should be far faster than .htaccess and a redirect

Comment: @PurpleFoxy. Define `too slow`

Comment: I doubt you want to use mod_rewrite for `thousand of different links` unless you have your own dedicated or VPS with plenty of resources to waste.

Comment: @Joren: two header requests instead of one.

Comment: Why not use routing with php? Instead of htaccess?

Comment: Better to use `RewriteMap` for this kind of task.

Comment: Because a PHP redirect is much slower http://serverfault.com/questions/88919/faster-option-redirect-via-php-to-php-or-apache-mod-rewrite-redirect-to-php

Comment: If you're so averse to using PHP and MySQL because they're "too slow", then why have you even bothered to tag PHP in this post.... and you're ignoring best advice because of some mistaken belief that playing with htaccess and redirects is faster than proper development tools - You don't do a PHP redirect, you check db and do a readfile or not

Comment: @anubhava can't see how RewriteMap can helps, I have not difficult rewrites to do.

Comment: Why do you need redirects anyway? This would require an additional HTTP access. Is it necessary that clients get the `/imgs/res2.jpg` URLs?

Comment: @MarkBaker is not a mistaken belief, PHP redirects will be always slower than .htaccess redirects, read the link I've posted.

Comment: I SAID DON'T USE PHP FOR A REDIRECT, USE IT FOR READFILE!!!!

Comment: guys, please use chat for your fireworks and post a solution when the fight is over

Comment: @PurpleFoxy: `RewriteMap` is not for complex rewrite it is for numerous similar rewrite mappings like yours.

Comment: @Scolytus each image can be accessed by different links, I must be able to disable a single alias and let the other works, and have copies of the same resource would make my hard disk full in few minutes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not do that by `.htaccess` but on the file system level. Just create symlinks, apache will serve them for you. The creation and management of the links can be done by a user interface.

This is also faster than redirecting.

Comment: I think I will use [symlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) to generate them since I need to get info from DB to generate the right alias. Thanks your seems the best solution so far.

Answer (score 4):

If you're determined to do this using only Apache you should use 'mod-rewrite'.  It has a mode where it consults an external mapping as specified in the [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm).  That external mapping can be a flat text file or single-table db file.  It's read on each invocation, but it's still much faster than using '.htaccess'.

But the symlinks are a better idea.